# How can I send a string from C++ winsock to Android via TCP socket?

Tags: java, android, c++, sockets, winsock

I want an android app and Windows C++ winsock to communicate using TCP sockets and I successfully sent a string from android to the C++ server but I cannot send string the other way around (from C++ server to Android client).

Here is the important C++ server part:

```
        recvbuf = "Back At  u \0";
        cout << " \n " << recvbuf << "\n";
        int iResult= send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, (int) strlen(recvbuf), 0);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);
```

And here is the android client recieving part:

```
class TextRcv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //TO SEND A STRING
            Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket= new Socket("192.168.1.5",8889);
            DataOutputStream oos= new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeBytes(String.valueOf(mystr.length()));
            oos.flush();
            byte[] bufferout=mystr.getBytes();
            oos.write(bufferout, 0, bufferout.length);
            oos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//to recieve a string
        String input =null;
        char[] buffin=new char[128];
        try {

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            in.read(buffin, 0, 128);
            input=String.valueOf(buffin);

            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return input;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String input) {
        super.onPostExecute(input);
        Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),input,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        }

}
```

The C++ output says that there is no error and that 11 bytes (length of the recvbuff string) are sent. But on the android the 'input' string is always null.
Here is the c++ server output:

```
Start Receving
length of string recieved in bytes =14
AndroidID - Hello World...

Done
Back At  u
Bytes Sent: 11

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: And where is the Android output? How do you know it's null? NB You are ignoring the length returned by `read()`, and assuming that it fills the buffer. It isn't specified to do that. And why are you sending the same thing twice?

Comment: @EJP I know the android output is null because the toast appears with no charachters. Also I have done if (input==null) check and it was true.

Comment: @EJP I don't know what you mean by sending the same thing twice. Please elaborate on that. Thanks

Comment: @EJP this part is for sending from Android to C++ and I first send the size of the string then the string itself. This is working no problem. The problem is in the other part of the code where I try to send a string from C++ to Android. Do you have any explanation why this is not working in my code sir?

Answer (score 0):

```
String input =null;
```

At this point `input` is null.

```
char[] buffin=new char[128];
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    in.read(buffin, 0, 128);
    input=String.valueOf(buffin);
```

This code is not correct, but if it executes at all, `input` cannot possibly be null. The correct code is as follows:

```
int count = in.read(buffin);
if (count > 0)
{
    input = new String(buffin, 0, count);
}
```

Back to your code:

```
    clientSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return input;
```

If `input` is still null at this point, there must have been an `IOException` which you haven't disclosed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think I understand why is it necessary to write IOException and what would happen if there was not? Also what do you think I should put in the IOException ? Forgive me but I am still learning :)

Comment: This is what I get when I try to toast out the 'input' string in the onpostexecute ():     https://www.dropbox.com/s/re1uiv0gh5raup4/Screenshot_2016-05-27-06-49-44.png?dl=0

Comment: I adjusted the code as you suggested but still... I also tried to toast out the count number and returned 0

Comment: I don't know what your question about 'why it is necessary to write IOException' means, but if you had an exception, or any other further output to report, you should have included it in your question, as text, not as a link. 'Toast out the count number' is meaningless. If you mean that `read()` returned zero, it is impossible unless you supplied a zero-length buffer.

Comment: HOW IS TOASTING OUT THE COUNT NUMBER MEANINGLESS! and how could I possibly check a variable's value on android!

Comment: It is meaningless because 'toasting' applies to pieces of bread, and you can CUT OUT THE SHOUTING right now. We are not deaf.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude I really appreciate your time but It is has been 3 days now and I can not get a solution to this problem